# Does CA AB-1666 actually have any practical effects?

Tags: california, texas, abortion

I'm having a hard time imagining any real scenario where [AB-1666](https://leginfo.legislature.ca.gov/faces/billTextClient.xhtml?bill_id=202120220AB1666) actually accomplishes anything.

Suppose you are a CA resident, and you buy plane tickets for your friend in TX to come to CA and get an abortion.  You are sued successfully in TX.  I mean, CA won't repo your car for TX because of AB-1666 but if you ever want to have necessary modern life things like a bank account, TX is going to grab it, right?  AB-1666 doesn't seem to protect stuff like that?

Does AB-1666 offer real protection to CA residents in these cases, or from a practical standpoint is it purely symbolic?

Comment: I think someone would need to be successfully sued in TX first, hardly a given.

Answer (score 2):

It is very hard to be sure what might happen in all possible situations where the Texas law is used to sue a person who assists another to obtain an abortion. There is as yet no case law, to the best of my knowledge, on applying such a law to a non-resident of Texas.

This bill, if passed, would seem to prohibit the California courts and officials from assisting in collection of any such judgement. It might well protect an account in a CA bank. Or it might be held invalid, as contrary to the Full Faith and Credit clause of the Federal constitution.